# Send an intent between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send a intent between to wactivites but seem to only get blank results when i try to pull the intent from the second activity.

Code :

Sending Class :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Posten.this, DetailView.class);
    intent.putExtra("sporingsnummer",et_sporingsnummer.getText());
    startActivity(intent);
```

Reciving Class :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       String sporingsnummer = extras.getString("sporingsnummer");
    }
```

The sporingsnummer in the second class is null but when i look at the bundle i can find the right information at mExtras -> mMap -> [0] -> value

How can i get this to work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following line:

```
intent.putExtra("sporingsnummer",et_sporingsnummer.getText());
```

needs to be this:

```
intent.putExtra("sporingsnummer",et_sporingsnummer.getText().toString());
```

The `getText()` methods only returns an `editable` not a String. You need to make the conversion from editable to String.